# can't clone git repository from another computer in the same LAN

Tags: git, windows-10, lan

I want to share the git repository with my teamers’ computer through LAN. I establish a repository in my own computer(named computer A) through the following command: (I have installed Git in all computers)

[git init --bare aoi_test.git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug22W.png)

And I changed the aoi_test.git file’s permission, like the followings:

[change the repository permission for sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp1sZ.png)

Also, I changed the “Advanced sharing settings” of computer A，like the followings:

[change the "Advanced sharing settings" in computer A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAUJS.png)

And computer A (IP is 192.168.2.207) is linked to the LAN. The aoi_test.git file’s sharing list like the following:

[aoi_test.git's sharing list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5KN0.png)

**In computer B （IP is 192.168.2.210， and** **the windows user account(my another computer) is the same as the one of computer A**）linked to the same LAN could clone the aoi_test.git repository from computer A, like the following:

[computer B can clone the repository through the LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXvoF.png)

But in the another computer C (IP is 192.168.2.222, my teamer’s computer) linked to same the LAN， can’t clone the aoi_test.git repository , what’s the problem and what should I do ?
The computer C also ping to computer A which the aoi_test.git repository in.

[computer C can't clone the repository through the LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trHa8.png)

Anyone can help me solve this? Thanks a lot for you guys!

Comment: Can you reach \\Desktop-msllr3j\aoi_test.git trough file explorer? I expect you can't, which would be the problem.

Comment: in computer B, it can be reached through file explorer, but can't in computer C.  @ikkentim

Comment: @WANQIAN, then that's what you need to fix. You can't clone from something you can't access.

Comment: but i input \\192.168.2.207\\aoi_tes.git through in computer C , it works...but why?(192.168.2.207 is the computer A's IP), why can't access by computer name instead computer's IP? While the IP changes always but also in the same LAN, just through the fixed IP can't push/pull in future if IP changes. what should i do ? @ikkentim

Comment: @Chris, thanks for your answer. i solved this problem by adding compter A's IP and its user account and user account's password to the credential manager of computer C. but i don't know why. I am fresh to git and LAN. Thanks again for you, Chris.